# What is idiomatic Julia style for by column or row operations?

Tags: r, julia

Apologies if this rather general - albeit still a coding question.

With a bit of time on my hands I've been trying to learn a bit of `Julia`. I thought a good start would be to copy the `R` `microbenchmark` function - so I could seamlessly compare R and Julia functions.

e.g. this is `microbenchmark` output for 2 R functions that I am trying to emulate:

```
Unit: seconds
expr                    min        lq    median        uq        max      neval
vectorised(x, y)    0.2058464 0.2165744 0.2610062 0.2612965  0.2805144     5
devectorised(x, y)  9.7923054 9.8095265 9.8097871 9.8606076 10.0144012     5
```

So thus far in Julia I am trying to write idiomatic and hopefully understandable/terse code. Therefore I replaced a double loop with a list comprehension to create an array of timings, like so:

```
function timer(fs::Vector{Function}, reps::Integer)
#    funs=length(fs)
#    times = Array(Float64, reps, funs)
#    for funsitr in 1:funs
#        for repsitr in 1:reps
#            times[reps, funs] = @elapsed fs[funs]()
#        end
#    end

    times= [@elapsed fs[funs]() for   x=1:reps, funs=1:length(fs)]
    return times
end
```

This gives an array of timings for each of 2 functions:

```
julia> test=timer([vec, devec], 10)
10x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.231621  0.173984
 0.237173  0.210059
 0.26722   0.174007
 0.265869  0.208332
 0.266447  0.174051
 0.266637  0.208457
 0.267824  0.174044
 0.26576   0.208687
 0.267089  0.174014
 0.266926  0.208741
```

My question (finally) is how do I **idiomatically** apply a function such as `min`, `max`, `median` across columns (or rows) of an array without using a loop?

I can of course do it easily for this simple case with a loop (sim to that I crossed out above)- but I can't find anything in the docs which is equivalent to say `apply(array,1, fun)` or even `colMeans`.

The closest generic sort of function I can think of  is

```
julia> [mean(test[:,col]) for col=1:size(test)[2]]
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 0.231621
 0.237173
```

.. but the syntax really really doesn't appeal. Is there a more natural way to `apply` functions across columns or rows of a multidimensional array in Julia?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anonymous functions **was** <strike>are currently</strike> slow in julia, so I would not use them for benchmarking unless you benchmark anonymous functions. That will give wrong performance prediction for code that does not use anonymous functions in performance critical parts of the code.

I think you want the two argument version of the reduction functions, like sum(arr, 1) to sum over the first dimension. If there isn't a library function available, you might use [reducedim](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.reducedim)

Comment: When you say "don't benchmark with anon function" do you mean force compilation once (other benchmarks funs do) and then time thereafter? the functions I am passing though not showing are predefined with arguments etc.. `means(arr,1)` is what I want here thx and I will check `reduce dim` now

Comment: No, I'm not thinking about the (questionable?) tricks to exklude compilation from timings. If you want good to test fast functions you will include a significant overhead for calling a function from a variable instead of calling the function directly by name. I think julia should include a macro to do benchmarking, but I don't think it currently have that.

Comment: yes the motivation to rewrite my own benchmark was partly because others precompiled and I thought this made comparison to other languages suspect. On anon functions I don't know how to write a general benchmark (accepting other funs) any other way...in Julia anyway.

Comment: I also think it is unfair that Julia devs want you to ensure that the relevant code paths has been executed once before measuring performance. The rationale is that that part if julia has not seen much optimization yet, because it is a young language, and it might be solved by caching the compiled code (like Python does with their .pyc files). Read about macros to learn how to write a benchmark the way you want.

Comment: FYI, anonymous functions are not slow anymore (since version 0.5). See https://julialang.org/blog/2016/10/julia-0.5-highlights

Answer (score 17):

The function you want is `mapslices`.

Answer (score 4):

I think @ivarne has the right answer (and have ticked it) but I just add that I made an `apply` like function:

```
function aaply(fun::Function, dim::Integer, ar::Array)
            if !(1 <= dim <= 2)
                    error("rows is 1, columns is 2")
            end
            if(dim==1)
                res= [fun(ar[row, :]) for row=1:size(ar)[dim]]
            end
            if(dim==2)
                res= [fun(ar[:,col]) for col=1:size(ar)[dim]]
            end
            return res
end
```

this then gets what I want like so:

```
julia> aaply(quantile, 2, test)
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 [0.231621,0.265787,0.266542,0.267048,0.267824]
 [0.173984,0.174021,0.191191,0.20863,0.210059]
```

where `quantile` is a built-in that gives min, lq, median, uq, and max.. just like microbenchmark.

**EDIT** Following the advice here I tested the new function `mapslice` which works pretty much like R `apply` and benchmarked it against the function above. Note that `mapslice` has `dim=1` as by column slice whilst `test[:,1]` is the first column... so the opposite of R though it has the same indexing?

```
# nonsense test data big columns
julia> ar=ones(Int64,1000000,4)
1000000x4 Array{Int64,2}:

# built in function
julia> ms()=mapslices(quantile,ar,1)
ms (generic function with 1 method)

# my apply function
julia> aa()=aaply(quantile, 2, ar)
aa (generic function with 1 method)

# compare both functions
julia> aaply(quantile, 2, timer1([ms, aa], 40))
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 [0.23566,0.236108,0.236348,0.236735,0.243008] 
 [0.235401,0.236058,0.236257,0.236686,0.238958]
```

So the funs are approximately as quick as each other. From reading bits of the Julia mailing list they seem to intend to do some work on this bit of Julialang so that making slices is by reference rather than making new copies of each slice (column row etc)...